# Why does chlorine become stable?

Tags: ions, electronegativity

We have an equation in our book

$$\ce{2Cl- (aq) + 2H2O -> 2OH-(aq) + H2(g) + Cl2(g)}$$

Why does chlorine become stable if it is electronegative?
Chlorine has excess of electrons, but later loses electron to become stable.

Is chlorine more stable than chloride?

Comment: For this process we need energy, and in this process called the chlor-alkali process, the energy is given by a electrolysis of the choride solution.

Comment: For more info Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloralkali_process

Comment: @PrachurjyaBiswas Thank you. So isfree energy positive? And will chlorine be more stable in an ionic form.

Comment: Yes the free energy of this rxn. is positive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemistry is not about finding the most stable state. In fact, a ‘most stable state’ has no meaning; it always depends on the conditions and other substances around.

Rather, chemistry is about following the pathway which leads to the greatest accessable reduction in Gibbs free energy $\Delta G$. If energy, in your case electricity, is supplied from the outside, the system’s Gibbs free energy may even be minimised by reacting towards substances with a lesser standard heat of formation.